# Дефис между выводом двух переменных

Tags: php

Нужно слитно вывести значения двух переменных, или поставить между ними _
Но каким-то образом там появляется -

```
$login = "Admin";
$ra = rand(000000000000000001,999999999999999999);
$vivod = "$login$ra";
echo $vivod;
// Результат - Admin-477547072, нужно Admin_477547072 или Admin477547072
```

Comment: Это точно весь код, относящийся к данной задаче? Потому что, можно до бесконечности его запускать, но ни дефиса, ни подчеркивания там не появится. Нужно подчеркивание? Значит ставьте:
$vivod = $login . '_' . $ra;

Comment: А не переполнение ли случается?

Comment: Всё верно, был минус

Answer (score 0, accepted):

это минус.

```
echo rand(999999999999999999,999999999999999999);//-1486618624
```

Answer (score 0):

$vivod = $login.'_'.abs($ra);

Comment: можно еще проще = $login.'_'.rand(1, PHP_INT_MAX);